# How can i get 2 column collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Hi just wondering why my collection view is still doing 1 column even the size of the cell is already small.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let flowayout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let space: CGFloat = (flowayout?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.left ?? 0.0) + (flowayout?.sectionInset.right ?? 0.0)
        let size:CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.size.width - space) / 2.0
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
    }
```

This is my code for delegate.

This is the values of insets in collectionview storyboard

[image]

And this is the result when i run it.
[image]

Anyone can help me with this. i just want to have a 2 column just like this screenshot [image]

Comment: First of all, just confirm you confirming `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to your controller and if you did your constraints are breaking. Just try to decrease the size of your cell manually and reset constraints and try.

Comment: @SatyenChauhan yes i have that delegate on my controller im printing the size of cell and its less than half the size of collectionview. When i put -1 on size it will change to 2 column. not sure why do i need to do that in order for it to change to 2 column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have constant cell width & height, you can set ItemSize once for layout. Use delegates to calculate size that could vary for each cell.

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let screenWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
let interItemSpacing = CGFloat(10)
let size = (screenWidth - interItemSpacing) / 2
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interItemSpacing
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```